# gazebo failing with .model

Tags: gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with the objects wihin gazebo_worlds, and whenever I try and spawn .model into gazebo using the command

rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file name.model -gazebo -model thing

My gazebo gets the error

[empty_world_server-1] process has died [pid 17337, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world __name:=empty_world_server __log:=/home/carol/.ros/log/715ceed4-bad5-11e1-9ffc-00268297df80/empty_world_server-1.log].
log file: /home/carol/.ros/log/715ceed4-bad5-11e1-9ffc-00268297df80/empty_world_server-1*.log

I am wondering if this is a common problem and if there is a fix to it by any chance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36893/gazebo-failing-with-.model/) by [Gen_Robotino](https://answers.ros.org/users/2585/gen_robotino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Kindly provide a little more detail about the model file, I am assuming you have gone through the tutorial at : http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/SpawningObjectInSimulation

as your command is correct. Let me know if this command works:-

```
rosrun gazebo spawn_model -gazebo -file `rospack find gazebo_worlds`/objects/coffee_cup.model -model coffee_cup -x 1.2 -z 1
```

Also from the folder where I have desk4.model,

rosrun gazebo spawn_model -gazebo -file desk4.model -model mydesk2

is able to spawn the table.

---

Originally posted by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) with karma: 339 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2012-06-26**:
I guess you should add `` for rospack find. rosrun gazebo spawn_model -gazebo -file `rospack find gazebo_worlds`/objects/coffee_cup.model -model coffee_cup -x 1.2 -z 1

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2012-06-27**:
Yuup rospack find gazebo_worlds should be in quotes. But is this command able to spawn the coffee_cup.model file?